# Why handlebars.js returns empty brackets?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to fill json data from local api. I followed document but It doesn't work and I get empty brackets instead of data.

html snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="form1" id="form1" class="ins-form-basic" >
    </select>
</div>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each items}}
    <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script>
$.get("/localApi", function(json) {
    var source = $("#sourceTemplate").html(),
        tmplt = Handlebars.compile(source),
        data = { items: json.item },
        output = tmplt(data);
    $("#form1").append(output);
});
</script>
```

I expected to get id and name and this is what I get.

```
<option value="{}">{}</option>
<option value="{}">{}</option>
<option value="{}">{}</option>
<option value="{}">{}</option>
```

The json from api is no problem. This is its structure.

```
{
    item: [
        {id:"1", name:"test1"},
        {id:"2", name:"test2"},
        {id:"3", name:"test3"},
        {id:"4", name:"test4"},
        ...
        ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I undertood what happened. A server side template(template_) library is sharing same symbol(brackets)

I'm trying to find another way.

Answer (score 2):

```
<option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
```

this should be

```
<option value="{{this.id}}">{{this.name}}</option>
```